# How to organize Javascript project to allow sharing of code between client SPA and Node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I am developing an application which comprises a SPA front end and a Rest back-end.

To implement the Rest back-end I am using Node and Express.

Considering that both front-end and back-end are written in JavaScript (and TypeScript), I would like to share some code between these 2 parts (namely Interfaces and simple utils).

So basically my project is composed of three parts: **Client**, **Server**, **Shared**. Therefore I am inclined to have a project directory structure similar to this:

```
ProjecFolder
   ClientFolder
     .....
   ServerFolder
     .....
   SharedFolder
     .....
```

I am looking for suggestions on how best organize my project. I have done some research and I have found this [interesting article](http://ramachandrang.com/2016/05/19/express-angular2-application-using-typescript-code-sharing-workflow.html) which suggests to use a mechanism based on Gulp tasks that copy all files from SharedFolder into both ClientFolder and ServerFolder and then runs transpling.

I am wondering whether there can be an alternative approach or tools that perform what otherwise has to be configures as Gulp workflow.

Comment: Split the code ! Imo is a bad idea deploy back and front in the same project

Comment: Webpack can generate two bundles without manually copying files, and with [tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) your two bundles should only contain what they needs.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use a package manager tool. When you have dependencies, and the requirements of the server changed, you have to change the module. You don't want the SPA (frontend), to break, when you need to make changes to the server.

This is why package managers give you versions. Each module that depends on your shared code, can use a different version of it. You can use NPM for that. Build a module, publish it, and install it on your frontend and backend.

Many times, in production you split the frontend and backend. The frontend may exist in a file storage system (S3, Google Cloud Storage and similar), and the backend executed on your servers. Then it will be harder to use the same files on both systems.

Comment: I agree to keep separate the code. In fact I do transpile separately client and server and I can deploy them independently. Still there are some things where both client and server should try to remain always in synch, to avoid surprises. This is for instance the case for the structures of the Jsons exchanges via Rest apis, which I model with Typescriprt interfaces. Hence my question. Anyways, I appreciate the suggestion of using a package manager.